# Why were Vandal Savage and the Flash due for a reckoning?

Tags: dc, young-justice

I was re-watching one of my favorite *Young Justice* episodes, "Coldhearted" (episode 20 of season 1). In it, Vandal Savage distracts Kid Flash for a while, hoping to prevent him from delivering a heart to a very important patient. Before the fight, Vandal says this:

> When I heard the authorities were cordining off this highway for a speedster, I assumed I'd be confronting Flash himself. **He and I are due for a reckoning**.

Is there a story attached to this? Does Vandal have a specific reason to want to fight the Flash himself?

Comment: We don't know yet.